# Краш exe-файла, созданного на Python

Tags: python

Скажу сразу - только начал изучать Python (1 язык программирования) поэтому во всем этом я полный чайник.
Поэтому прошу не относиться ко мне строго :)
Написал простенький калькулятор, сделал exe файл.
Когда открываю файл, все работает.Ввожу выполняемое действие (например: +), ввожу первое число, затем второе, нажимаю Enter и все, файл крашится :(.
В чем может быть проблема?
Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Когда те же действия выполняете не создавая exe файл, то все работает?

Comment: Сразу скажу - проблему я уже решил.
Но все равно спасибо, что откликнулись!
Если вам интересно, то можете читать далее:
Вообщем, сначала файл крашился сразу же ( при запуске ), я в конце кода прописал input (), после этого появилась выше описанная проблема.
Я не знаю, правильным ли было моё решение, но я зашел в Sublime text ( там я и писал свой код ) и перед input было 4 пробела, я их убрал и все заработало.

Comment: Значит проблема была не в exe, а ошибка синтаксиса в вашем коде - отступ там где его не должно было быть.

Comment: Да, я это понял, спасибо вам :)